# How to Draw a point in a QPixmap Image?

Tags: c++, image, qt, user-interface, qtgui

I have a project where i want to draw a point into a image inside a QPixmap. The point would be draw with the mouse click on the QLabel. I created a `eventFilter()` which corresponds to mouse click. When I click with the mouse, these eventFilter is called and draw a point in the image, but my code doesn't works. I tried many others options like subclassing the QLabel, but didn't work either.

And sometimes my compiler shows these error messages:

```
QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 2
QPainter::setPen: Painter not active
QPainter::drawPoints: Painter not active
QPainter::end: Painter not active, aborted
```

but I don't understand, because the Qt documentation says that is allowed use the QPainter outside of paintEvent just using with QPixmap.

Below is my code with the method that starts the QPainter.

```
bool mainwindow::eventFilter(QObject* watched, QEvent* event) {
if ( watched != ui->labelScreen )
    return false;
if ( event->type() != QEvent::MouseButtonPress )
    return false;
const QMouseEvent* const me = static_cast<const QMouseEvent*>( event );
//might want to check the buttons here
const QPoint p = me->pos(); //...or ->globalPos();

ui->label_Xget->setNum(this->xReal);
ui->label_Yget->setNum(this->yReal);

///////////////////////////////////

QPixmap pix;
pix.fromImage(QImage::fromData("C:/Users/Syn/Pictures/imagem137.jpg"));

QPainter *painter = new QPainter(&pix);

painter->setPen(Qt::red);
painter->drawPoint(p.x(), p.y());
ui->labelScreen->setPixmap(pix);
painter->end();

///////////////////////////////////


return false;
}
```

Someone would can help me solve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error messages are not from your compiler, they happen at runtime, and you can't be sure whether the code you quote above is their cause.

There are several problem:

1. `QPixmap::fromImage` is a static method that returns a pixmap. You're ignoring its return value. The correct way to use it would be:

   ```
   // C++11
   auto pix = QPixmap::fromImage(QImage{"filename"});
   // C++98
   QPixmap pix(QPixmap::fromImage(QImage("filename")));
   ```
2. You can pass the filename directly to `QPixmap` constructor:

   ```
   // C++11
   QPixmap pix{"filename"};
   // C++98
   QPixmap pix("filename");
   ```
3. You're leaking the painter instance. You should avoid any dynamic memory allocation unless you truly need it. Also, store `ui` by value - it's cheaper that way.
4. It is a very bad idea to do any blocking I/O, such as reading a file, in event handlers. Preload and store the pixmap as a member of the `MainWindow` class.

Thus (in C++11):

#### Interface

```
template <class F>
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
  QPixmap m_clickPixmap;
  Ui::MainWindow ui;
  bool eventFilter(QObject*, QEvent*) override;
public:
  MainWindow(QWidget * parent = nullptr);
};
```

#### Implementation

```
void loadImage(const QString & fileName, QObject * context, F && functor) {
  QtConcurrent::run([=]{
    QImage img{fileName};
    if (img.isNull()) return;
    QTimer::singleShot(0, context, functor, img);
  });
}

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget * parent) :
  QMainWindow{parent}
{
  loadImage("C:/Users/Syn/Pictures/imagem137.jpg", this, [this](const QImage & img){
    m_clickPixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(img);
  });
  ui.setupUi(this);
}

bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject* watched, QEvent* event) {
  if ( watched != ui.labelScreen )
    return false;
  if ( event->type() != QEvent::MouseButtonPress )
    return false;
  auto const me = static_cast<const QMouseEvent*>(event);
  auto const p = me->pos(); //...or ->globalPos();       
  ui.label_Xget->setNum(this->xReal);
  ui.label_Yget->setNum(this->yReal);

  auto pix{m_clickPixmap};
  QPainter painter(&pix);
  painter.setPen(Qt::red);
  painter.drawPoint(p.x(), p.y());
  painter.end(); // probably not needed
  ui.labelScreen->setPixmap(pix);
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I tried your sugestion but still shows the same error messages. And in the labelScreen is setting a empty pixmap, and displaying nothing on the label. :/

Comment: Are you sure that this code causes any problem? Disable the code and see if you still have the issue. This code should work just fine.

Comment: Are you sure you want to static_cast instead of dynamic_cast?

Comment: I discovered the error messages problem. The QPixmap pix is not loading the QImage input. With pix.load() the image loads fine in the pix. But i need to use a file from QImage in my project. You know how can i solve this problem? Thanks for all the answers.

Comment: @JosephMalicke Yes, it should be a static cast: at that point, the type of the event is known. `QEvent` has its own type id mechanism.

Comment: I tried your suggestion @KubaOber and its works now. But i discovered myself another simple way to solve my problem. I just changed the QPixmap to a QImage variable inside QPainter and converting to pixmap in labelScreen->setPixmap(). Now Qpainter is drawing the image. Again, Thanks for all answers.